# How can I startup terminator with commands prepared?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, terminator

I would like to mimic the behaviour of Byobu's "send-keys" functionality. This will send keys to the window, but it will not execute them.

After setting a custom profile in Terminator, I would like to open it and see the following display:

[image: Desired behaviour]

I haven't seen this in any documentation. Is this possible, or is there a workaround that can accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not aware of such functionality, although it would be quite easy to add (using `vte_terminal_feed_child()`). I recommend that you file a bug (feature request) under https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/ .

Comment: Could you elaborate on "vte_terminal_feed_child()". Is this coming from Terminators source?

Comment: Just forward this to Terminator's maintainer, he will understand :) (It's a method of VTE, the terminal emulator widget behind Terminator, GNOME Terminal and many others. When coding in python, it's probably called `feed_child` on a Vte object.)

Comment: Yes, I was taking a look at the source code. I'm working on making a pull request, though there's not much documentation. I've realized now why I like C++. Python is great, but it is not easy to figure out how the objects of another person's project are constructed. It also seems that there is a big wishlist so I'd probably have to do this myself if I want it anytime soon.

Comment: Now that I've grepped Terminator's source for the word "feed", seems there's a "custom_commands" plugin which contains it. It might be doing what you're looking for, or at least something close enough to give you some guidance, dunno.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm going to submit a pull request. :) Giving me the reference to feed_child() was a good start point, though it was a little tricky to sort through their source.

Comment: I'll update as an answer once I've corresponded and see if they accept my pull request.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but this can be done by setting the `Custom command` of the terminal within the layout definition. The following (based on [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/5smcjb/terminator_how_can_i_have_a_command_ready_but_not/)) does the job:

```bsh
read -p "command" && command; bash
```

This will display the command and wait for <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Once the command is executed, the terminal is maintained opened.